# How to converte Lambda expression output to List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am selecting the checked rows from Gridview. To achieve this i have written a lambda expression using dynamic keyword.

```
var dn = gvLoans.Rows.OfType<dynamic>().Where(s => s.FindControl("chkSelect").Checked == true).Select(s => s.FindControl("lblCD")).ToList();
```

I want the output of this in List. Can it be achieved by extending the query or i have to write foreach statement.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already have a `.ToList()` which will give you a List. What's your problem?

Comment: It doesnt allow typecasting dynamic output

Comment: You'll have to post the error message you get for your question to make any sense.

Comment: Thanks i got the solution                                 List<int> lst = gvRankDetails.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Where(s => ((CheckBox)s.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked == true)
                                                                        .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(((Label)s.FindControl("lblCD")).Text)).ToList();

Answer (score 4):

Blatant rip of the comment posted as an answer.

```
List<int> lst = gvRankDetails.Rows
    .OfType<GridViewRow>()
    .Where(s => ((CheckBox)s.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked) 
    .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(((Label)s.FindControl("lblCD")).Text))
    .ToList();
```

OfType is necessary, as GridViewRowCollection implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public class GridViewRowCollection : ICollection, IEnumerable
```

Comment: Why is the `OfType` necessary? Also, I think `int.Parse` is nicer than `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: The OfType isn't necessary, and it doesn't really matter how you try to coerce the int does it? Like my answer says, blatant rip of the answer posted in comments. I only put it here since the comment should have been an answer.

Comment: No way It does work if i remove .OfType<GridViewRow>()--Gridviewrowcollection does not contain a definition for a where....

Comment: The `OfType` is necessary because `GridViewRowCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>` -- the `OfType` gives the `T` to `Where`.

Comment: @Gabe, that's originally what I had written - then I figured that LINQ could infer the type since the enumerator produces items of GridViewRow. Should have tested first. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dn = gvLoans.Rows
  .OfType<dynamic>()
  .Where(s => s.FindControl("chkSelect").Checked == true)
  .Select(s => s.FindControl("lblCD"))
  .Cast<someType>().ToList();
```

same code but add **.Cast<someType>()** before ToList()